# mysql perform mysql orderby first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I just want to ask how can the order by clause be performed first before the actual select statement.

I have query under PHP:

```
mysql_query("SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang) AS locations 
             FROM postflight 
             WHERE rno='$cc' 
             ORDER BY sfno ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

What the query does is to concat the values first before sorting it. What I want is to sort it by ascending first before concatting it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, try

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang ORDER BY sfno ASC)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

or if you want to add `SEPARATOR`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang ORDER BY sfno ASC SEPARATOR '-')
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f667/6)

Comment: One more thing, can I apply the SEPARATOR '-' like this, `GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang SEPARATOR '-' ORDER BY sfno ASC)` or my syntaxt is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @xjshiya it should be `GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang ORDER BY sfno ASC SEPARATOR '-')`

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(sample_lang ORDER BY sfno ASC SEPARATOR '-')` is the correct syntax. :)))